# Prove that $\lim_{x\to a}\bigr(C f(x)\bigl) = C \lim_{x\to a} f(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing, alternative-proof

I would like to prove the following:

> Prove that $\lim_{x\to a}\bigr(C f(x)\bigl) = C \lim_{x\to a} f(x)$, where $C$ is constant.

First I checked some proofs on internet. One of the proofs that I came across is [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LimitProofs.aspx) (Property $1$). (Click on the image to expand)

[image]

However, considering that this property is quite basic, I wonder whether there is a shorter (and less cryptic) way to prove that.

My feeble attempt was:

According to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)):

> A limit is the value that a function (or sequence) "approaches" as the
>   input (or index) "approaches" some value, or in other words:
>
> $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$$ where $L$ is some constant.

Since $C$ is constant and unrelated to value of $x$, when $x$ approaches $a$, $C$ remains unchanged and $f(x)$ approaches $L$, in other words:

$\lim_{x\to a}\bigr(C f(x)\bigl) = CL$, which can be rewritten as $C \lim_{x\to a} f(x)$

---

Very likely that my attempt is incorrect, hence I would like to ask you, is there a better (and shorter) alternative to show that $\lim_{x\to a}\bigr(C f(x)\bigl) = C \lim_{x\to a} f(x)$

Comment: Nope. If you want to prove it you gotta use some $\varepsilon$s and $\delta$s.

Comment: There is a more formal definition of the notion of limit, if you are trying to prove this, you should use them. for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(ε,_δ)-definition_of_limit

Comment: As a general rule when you read mathematics on wikipedia (and to some extent in all other sources) is to keep in mind that anything coming before the paragraph "*Definition*", albeit interesting, is quite close meaningless. In fact, the most effective way to read such an article on wikipedia is to flat-out ignore those parts, and perhaps come back to them later.

Comment: Sidenote: if $C=0$, the first limit exists, but the second limit may not, which is troublesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $|Cf(x)-CL|=|C||f(x)-L|$, the simplest and possibly only way to complete the proof with the $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ terminology is to let $|f(x)-L|<\frac{\epsilon}{|C|}$ for every $\epsilon>0$. I don't see a way that is shorter than the pasted image unless you have already proven $3$ and $7$.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to show is that *if* for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$, *then* for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that $|Cf(x)-CL|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$.